# Can you send json from VisualForce to Apex and have it be valid?

Tags: apex, visualforce, json

I have this JSON object that I've gotten from the front end. I want to send it to Apex and finally send it to my external API.

### Visualforce:

```
 ct_4_sf.RecordingTest.saveVideo(
     data, //{key:'value',key2:'value2'}
     function(response){

     }
 );
```

If I attempt to just send it from visualforce to this apex function:

### Apex:

```
@RemoteAction
global static String saveVideo(String data) {
    System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO,'saving ' + data);
    return Connector.saveVideo(JSON.serialize(data));
}
```

The `saving` log will print something like this:

```
{key=value, key2=value2}
```

All the colons are now replaced with equal signs, which is invalid JSON.

How can I either turn this back into valid json, or send valid json in a way that it doesn't corrupt on the other side?

Comment: So the inbound JSON that you are passing to data is `{key:value, key2:value2}`?

Comment: @DanielBallinger Not exactly. It's actual data, but yes, it's in valid json format. That's what I'm sending as a parameter when I call `saveVideo` from Visualforce.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert the JSON into string before sending to controller using JSON.stringify(). Please check below link,

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Also if there is no other operation that needs to be done in controller before sending to external system. Try to do it in page only using javascript/jQuery AJAX

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 1):

One way i can think of is to have a class for your JSON .

```
public class wrapperclass{
  public String key;    //value
   public String key2;  //value2
 }
```

Your remoting function will be tweeked like below

```
@RemoteAction
global static wrapperclass saveVideo(wrapperclass wrap) {
   return wrap;
}
```

Another alternate approach can be as below if your keys are dynamic in nature

```
global class RecordingTest{
  @RemoteAction
  global static map<string,Object> saveVideo(map<string,Object> inputmap) {
     return inputmap;
  }
}
```

The page code that I tested with is as below

```
<apex:page controller="RecordingTest">

<script type="text/javascript">
     function RemoteTest() {
     var testdata={key:'value',key2:'value2'};
    Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
        '{!$RemoteAction.RecordingTest.saveVideo}',
        testdata, 
        function(result, event){
            if (event.status) {

              console.log(result);//print the log and inspect console to see result returned in form of JS object.You can generate string from JSON object using stringify

   console.log(JSON.stringify(result));



            } else if (event.type === 'exception') {

            } else {

            }
        }, 
        {escape: true}
    );
}
</script>

<button onclick="RemoteTest()">Test</button>
```